# dynamic thumbnail of table row data

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I was wondering how to make the dynamic thumbnail of logos from the rows of the table like the picture below?

[image]

I am using the code below:

```css
.numberCircle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 8px;
  background: #ddd;
  border: 2px solid #666;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font: 16px Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<?php 
    $words = preg_split("/\s+/", "Unnamed Template",2);
    
     foreach ($words as $w) {
       
       $acronym .= $w[0];
       
     }
    ?>
<div class="numberCircle">
  <?php echo $acronym;?>
</div>
```

I am using PHP, HTML and Bootstrap for the web development. Is there any packages/tools to get like this?

Thanks.

Comment: Which PHP framework/CMS you are using? Or raw PHP?

Comment: I am using raw PHP with Bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JS an jQuery instead. Dont forget to add jQuery lib.

```
<div class="numberCircle"></div>
<p class="content">Lorem Ipsum Dormitor</p>

<script>
    var text = $('.content').text().split(" ");
    var cap = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        var getCap = text[i].charAt(0);
        cap.push(getCap)
    }

    $('.numberCircle').text(cap[0] + cap[1])
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try media component of bootstrap

```
<div class="media">
   <img src="..." class="mr-3" alt="...">
    <div class="media-body">
       <h5 class="mt-0">Media heading</h5>
       Cras sit amet nibh libero.
    </div>
</div>
```

This is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/n2javtos/

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was wondering is there any way we get the avatar symbols(UT) instead of we type it?